# Connecting remotely to mysql running in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Windows Server 2012 instance created on Amazon EC2. I have installed MySQL and have a database set up for testing and I have a user created with all privileges. I wan't to connect to this database remotely from another windows machine but the connection won't work. I have opened port 3306 and allowed all traffic (again just for testing). I can ping the server just fine but when I try and connect using the command prompt as so:

```
MySQL Server/bin>mysql -h "IP address for my instance" -u User -p"password"
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on "host" (10060)
```

I have no idea what's causing this. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I created another user with privileges using this command:

```
mysql>CREATE USER 'testUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass';
mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testUser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error `10060` means that you are not allowed to connect remotely.

It won't work if you've created a user `yourName@localhost`. Try to create a user using the wildcard host, `%` : `yourName@%`.

Comment: I thought I had done that already but I will make a new user to be sure thanks!

Comment: Is this still the same error that you get ? (`10060`) A little googling gave me this : http://kylegoslin.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/109/ Good luck !

Comment: @Martin, I disagree.  Windows error 10060 is `WASETIMEDOUT`, suggesting that a firewall is blocking the connection request -- not a permissions issue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out the following line from your my.ini.  On Windows you can find it in the MySQL installation directory, usually something like "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\"

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Basically this telling mysql to listen only to requests coming from 127.0.0.1. This is the default setting for security reasons.  You can also do something like

```
bind-address = <ip address of one of your network interfaces>
```

That will essentially only listen to requests on that particular network interface.

If you comment out the `bind-address` option you may want to configure your AWS Security groups accordingly to prevent unauthorized access.

Comment: I have tried finding this file but I cannot find it anywhere, I'm running MySQL 5.6 if that makes a difference

Comment: On Windows, the file is `my.ini` instead of `my.cnf`.

Comment: some explanation of why this is necessary would be nice - ie explain that by default (for security reasons), mysql only listens for connections from localhost.